# How to visualize saved data after extracting it from the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: This is what I have extracted][image: sample of original dataset]

Basically I want to extract the highest value count of the genre for each year and then plot it in a bar chart to answer the question - Which genre is most popular from year to year?

Comment: Post a minimum reproducible example that can be copied. Follow the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is create `3 columns DataFrame` by #[`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = (temp_1.reset_index(name='count')
            .drop_duplicates('release_year')
            .pivot('release_year','genres','count'))
```

Or remove duplicates in `MultiIndex` by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last create `3 columns DataFrame`:

```
df = (temp_1[~temp_1.index.get_level_values('release_year').duplicated()]
            .unstack()
            .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Last plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed to do.